# PHP trim string from first occurrence of particular word, to occurrence of another word/char

Tags: php, string, trim

I want to trim a string which has some javascript code and possibly some other programming languages scattered through it.

For example, I have this string:

> "var itemNumber = window.ebayItemID ? window.ebayItemID : -1; function passpara(){return '&id=831556&itembgcolor=0x000066&bordercolor=0x000006&storewindowbgcolor=0xFFFFFF&toptextcolor=0x000066&bottomtextcolor=0x000066&stripcolor=0x99BBDD&auctionclosemessagecolor=0x99BBDD&emptyboxmessagecolor=0x99BBDD&buttovercolor=0x99BBDD&buttoutcolor=0x99BBDD&searchtitlecolor=0x000066&searchbuttbgcolor=0x000066&searchbutttextcolor=0x000006&searchbuttbordercolor=0x000066&itemhighlightcolor=0xFFF000&navbuttonactivecolor=0xFFF000&navbuttonoutlinecolor=0xFFFFFF&navbuttoninactivebgcolor=0xFFF000&siteid=123&cat=112847&item=' + itemNumber + '&baseurl='+escape(location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));}  function passparaSC(){return '&baseurl='+escape(location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)) + '&sitebaseurl=http://www.auctiva.com&tagNum=1';}  XBOX The cd is cleaned and tested and works perfectly.  What you see is what you get. Payment within 5 days after the auction ended. All the articles I sell, are secondhand unless otherwise described. The articles may have some traces of being used (little scratches, discolorations, extra folds in the box, etc.) If you have any questions feel free to ask, I'll be happy answering them.If yoy wan't more pictures,just let me know. I'm not responsible for lost packages by the postal service.De cd is gereinigd en getest en werkt perfect. Wat je ziet is wat je krijgt.Betaling binnen de 5 dagen na afloop van de veiling.Alle artikelen die ik verkoop zijn 2de hands tenzij anders beschreven. De artikelen kunnen lichte gebruikssporen bevatten (kleine krasjes,verkleuringen,kreuken in het doosje, enz...) Ik ben niet verantwoordelijk voor pakjes die verloren gaan of beschadigd worden tijdens de verzending. Indien je nog vragen zou hebben stel ze me gerust. Meer fotoâ€™s op aanvraag.Le cd est nettoyÃ© et testÃ© et fonctionne parfaitement. Ce que vous voyez est ce que vous allez recevoir. Payer dans les 5 jours  aprÃ¨s  la fin de la vente aux enchÃ¨res. Tous les articles que je vent, sont usagÃ©s sinon autrement dÃ©crit. Les articles peuvent avoir de traces dâ€™usage (petites rayures, dÃ©coloration, plusieurs plis dans la boÃ®te, etc.)Je ne suis pas responsible pour des parquets perdus ou des parquets qui sont nuis par le facteur. Payment:   I accept banc transfer orders and paypal payments. Payment must happen within 5 days after ending the auction. Shipping: I'll ship worldwide. I always combine multiple purchaces. You're purchace will be send within 48 houres after reseving the payment. "

Obviously, the string is littered with code. Is there a way to trim a string from beginning till the end of the code section?

I've already looked at the strip_tags(), str_replace() and trim() functions.

Many thanks in advance, Thomas

EDIT:

This is what I have right now.

```
$result_strip = strip_tags($result_strip, "<style>");

    $substring = substr($result_strip, strpos($result_strip, "<style"), strpos($result_strip, "</style>") + 2);
    $result_strip = str_replace($substring, " ", $result_strip);
    $result_strip = str_replace(array("\t", "\r", "\n"), " ", $result_strip);
    $result_strip = preg_replace('/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/is', " ", $result_strip);
    $result_strip = trim($result_strip);
    $result_strip = str_replace("&nbsp;",' ',$result_strip);
    $result_strip = str_replace("bsp;",' ',$result_strip);
    $result_strip = trim($result_strip,chr(0xC2).chr(0xA0));
```

This strips the string of the html and css and such, and the &sbnp; tags.

Comment: Has it, by any chance, already had `strip_tags` (or one of those other functions you mentioned) applied to it?

Comment: If you are working with a full HTML file, you can use DomDocument to remove specific tags and wholes sections. Or you can just use `preg_replace()`.

Comment: You could try using a combination of `substr()` and `strrpos()`, to get the substring until the last `}` character is found, like so:
`$non_code = substr($your_str,strrpos($your_str,"}"));`
Obviously you'll need to check whether or not this would work in all cases.

Comment: @rbock This works, but is this stripping everything from the front of the string to the last piece of the function? 

If so, then this won't work..

Comment: @ThomasBrandhorst I did not see your edit. I'll delete my answer, as I said, it is definitely not a robust solution

Comment: @rbock No problem, thanks anyway! Do you know any other way to delete the section, no matter where it is in the string?

Comment: @ThomasBrandhorst check the documentation for `substr()` and `strpos()` (and its variations). You can select a part of a string if you know the starting and finishing index of the substring you want to select.